# Can I use jquery within my custom Polymer elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, polymer, shadow-dom

The Polymer documentation says:

> Polymer provides a custom API for manipulating DOM such that local DOM and light DOM trees are properly maintained. These methods and properties have the same signatures as their standard DOM equivalents, except that properties and methods that return a list of nodes return an Array, not a NodeList.
>
> **Note: All DOM manipulation must use this API, as opposed to DOM API directly on nodes.**

Jquery has *a lot* of useful methods though, which make my life easier, like `toggleClass`, `hasClass`, `addClass`, `one`...

I have been able to use some of these methods without consequence in my elements, but I am wondering what exactly the semantics are behind the bold part of the above quote, so I can reason about things more clearly.

Note: I'm not talking about using jquery in the main document, I am talking about using it when I am *inside* the shadow boundary, like in an element's `ready` callback for instance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can, actually. You'll just have to use `Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector` and wrap that returned element in jquery.

Here's an example. http://jsbin.com/purudu/edit?html,output

Comment: what about querying methods, like `.find`? so if I had `$(Polymer.dom(this.root)).find('.shadowELement')` would that be okay?

Comment: @LukeP After some experimenting, I realized that you can use `$(this.root)` when Polymer is using the shadow dom instead of the shady dom.